# Can jdk.incubator.vector process String contents in Java 20?

Tags: java, string, vectorization

I am interested in experimenting with vectorization of a number of algorithms on Strings.

I am familiar with the implementation of compact strings and how not all Strings in Java are laid out in memory the same way, but I nevertheless think there might be some read-only mechanism to efficiently access the underlying representations of Strings.  I don't see, for example, any VarHandle access to string elements, nor do I see access in the MemorySegment API, nor do I see any functions in ShortVector, which I would expect to handle char operations if they were possible.

I can, of course, do explicit copying from strings to bytes to jdk.incubator.vector Vectors, but since the goal is investigating the possibilities of performance optimization, that seems unlikely to produce ideal results.

(It's quite plausible that there is no copy free answer to my question, since such an algorithm would be sensitive to the implementation of Strings which has notably changed over time and might be difficult to future proof, but there might also be solutions that reduce the amount of copying.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*not all Strings in Java are laid out in memory the same way*". Strings are just `byte[]` now. They used to be `char[]`. They are laid out the same. The difference is the *encoding*: either 1 byte per char or 2. There are package-private methods to get both [the encoding byte](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L4696) and the raw bytes.

Comment: That distinction is what I mean, sorry.  I do see the package-private access, but I don't know if there is any public API with which the underlying bytes can be accessed (even read only).

Comment: (An unsafe, Unsafe, or incubator API would suffice.)

Comment: I suppose what you'd be looking for is a hypothetical `ByteVector.fromString(...)` (it doesn't exist), because usually any attempt to get the byte[] from a String (e.g. getBytes) will result in a defensive copy, because all arrays are mutable and there's no way to prevent modification.

Comment: Yes.  ByteVectors, fortunately, are not mutable; a read-only MemorySegment or ByteBuffer would also seem like a safe API to provide.  Neither seem to be available, but perhaps there's something I've overlooked.

Comment: Even a getBytes with a (from, to) argument and a Charset (unlike the deprecated version) that works particularly well for ASCII would reduce the copying significantly.

Comment: I’m not well versed in applications of vectors, but I at least understand that you don’t want to copy String contents, so would something like `string.chars().forEach(intVector::add)` be of any use?  [chars()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars()) is a stream, so I assume it does not copy anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Vectorization ideally wants things about memory locality and contiguous memory; Streams and Spliterators are ill-suited to that work.  It wouldn't be meaningfully better than an explicit charAt loop.  That's not the worst option, but it would involve a bunch of redundant copying.